# PostgreSQL - aggregate series interval 2 years

Tags: postgresql, date, sum, aggregate, series

I have some

```
        id_merchant    |    data    |  sell
                    11 | 2009-07-20 | 1100.00
                    22 | 2009-07-27 | 1100.00
                    11 | 2005-07-27 |  620.00
                    31 | 2009-08-07 | 2403.20
                    33 | 2009-08-12 | 4822.00
                    52 | 2009-08-14 | 4066.00
                    52 | 2009-08-15 |  295.00
                    82 | 2009-08-15 |    0.00
                    23 | 2011-06-11 |  340.00
                    23 | 2012-03-22 | 1000.00
                    23 | 2012-04-08 | 1000.00
                    23 | 2012-07-13 |   36.00
                    23 | 2013-07-17 | 2480.00
                    23 | 2014-04-09 | 1000.00
                    23 | 2014-06-10 | 1500.00
                    23 | 2014-07-20 |  700.50
```

I want to create table as select with interval 2 years. First date for merchant is min(date). So i generate series (min(date)::date,current(date)::date,'2 years')

I want to get to table like that:

```
        id_merchant |   data          |  sum(sell)
                 23 | 2011-06-11      |  12382.71
                 23 | 2013-06-11      |  12382.71
                 23 | 2015-06-11      |  12382.71
```

But there is some mistake in my query because sum(sell) is the same for all series and the sum is wrong. Event if i sum sale ther is about 6000 not 12382.71.

My query:

> ```
> select m.id_gos_pla,
>        generate_series(m.min::date,dath()::date,'2 years')::date,
>        sum(rch.suma)
> from   rch, minmax m
> where  rch.id_gos_pla=m.id_gos_pla
> group by m.id_gos_pla,m.min,m.max
> order by 1,2;
> ```

Pls for help.

Comment: Have a hunch that your grouping is done the wrong way, but more importantly have absolutely no idea what are you trying to achieve. Are you sure that the three line output above, is what you 'want to get' from the above data? In other words, could you give 'what you want' rather than what your queries returns, for us to understand what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
select
        periods.id_merchant,
        periods.date as period_start,
        (periods.date + interval '2' year - interval '1' day)::date as period_end,
        coalesce(sum(merchants.amount), 0) as sum
    from
    (
        select
                id_merchant,
                generate_series(min(date), max(date), '2 year'::interval)::date as date
            from merchants
                group by id_merchant
    ) periods
    left join merchants on
            periods.id_merchant = merchants.id_merchant and
            merchants.date >= periods.date and
            merchants.date < periods.date + interval '2' year
        group by periods.id_merchant, periods.date
        order by periods.id_merchant, periods.date
```

We use sub-query to generate date periods for each `id_merchant` according to the first date for this merchant and required interval. Then join it with `merchants` table on date within period condition and group by `merchant_id` and period (`periods.date` is the starting period date which is enough). And finally we take everything we need: starting date, ending date, merchant and sum.